# Monitoring Datomic in CloudWatch without CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, datomic, cloudwatch

I'm trying to monitor the Datomic transactor in CloudWatch. According to the [documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/aws.html#s3-log-storage) (section "Using S3 log storage and CloudWatch metrics with other storages") I should be able to do it simply by setting a couple config variables and making sure the instance is launched with an appropriate IAM policy.

I set up the appropriate configs in the `transactor.properties` file I pass to the transactor when it starts:

```
aws-cloudwatch-region=us-east-1
aws-cloudwatch-dimension-value=transactor-staging
```

and set the instance into an IAM role called `datomic` with a policy that contains:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":
    [{"Resource":"*",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": ["cloudwatch:PutMetricData", "cloudwatch:PutMetricDataBatch"],
      "Condition":{"Bool":{"aws:SecureTransport":"true"}}}]}
```

But when I look in CloudWatch I can't find any metrics associated with Datomic or my transactor. When I run the transactor I don't see any error messages in the logs.

Is there something else I need to do? I should also note I'm not using CloudFormation, so I haven't run through any of the CloudFormation Datomic init stuff if that's relevant here.

Thanks!

Comment: using datomic version 0.9.5344

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this working? I'm trying to monitor a Datomic transactor that not hosted on AWS, using Cloudwatch. Thanks!

Comment: yes. it turns out of all the stupid things i had an extra space in the config file on one of the cloudwatch config lines in transator.properties. removing it fixed it.